# ObjectInputStream : StreamCorruptedException

Tags: java

Hi everbody i have to write a server which communicate over a socket connection.
The client sends Objects to the server and the server prints it to console.

```
public class ConnectionListener {

ServerSocket providerSocket;
Socket connection = null;
ObjectOutputStream out;
ObjectInputStream in;
Object message;

void runListener()
{
    try{
        providerSocket = new ServerSocket(2004, 10);
        System.out.println("Waiting for connection");
        connection = providerSocket.accept();
        System.out.println("Connection received from " + connection.getInetAddress().getHostName());
        in = new ObjectInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
        out = new ObjectOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
        do{
            message = in.readObject();
            System.out.println("client>" + message);
        }while(!message.equals("bye"));
    }
    catch(IOException ioException){
        ioException.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally{
        try{
            in.close();
            out.close();
            providerSocket.close();
        }
        catch(IOException ioException){
            ioException.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

}

But i always become a StreamCorruptedException at this line:

```
in = new ObjectInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
```

Can Anyone help me?

Thank you

Comment: The other end of the connection may be sending you bad data.  Impossible to be sure from what you've given us.

Comment: What is the client side sending over the connection? `ObjectInputStream` expects a serialized Java object. Is that what the client is sending?

Comment: can u post the sender side code too ?

Comment: I´m connecting to the server via telnet and sending normal text input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I´m connecting to the server via telnet and sending normal text input.

So the other end isn't using `ObjectOutputStream` at all, so using `ObjectInputStream` is just nonsense.

If you want to just read text, use `BufferedReader.readLine()`.

Comment: Ok that means to test this server i have to write a client which uses Objectoutputstream. right?

Comment: Correct. And when you do, you need to create the `ObjectOutputStream` *before* the `ObjectInputStream`, at at least one end. For safety do that at both ends, then you can't be wrong.